# typescript tuple refinement via the type of one tuple?

Tags: typescript

It seems that I can refine tuples with null checks (`=== null`), but I can't figure out how to refine them on type checks.  Is this possible?  [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwEEAKASgC54BtAZwxi1QHMAaeVZCCAXXgB8anbu3qMWPANwAoFOmx54pMvADe06fC3wweevAAe8ALwFi5GZu1ZE8EgeoAGPsdccuEFeu0+dejPAAniaG1ACMUvAA9FFBIWJMzFZaAL7SadKgkLAIcpi4+Fi0AMoMifZUUKiBlIbwRfAJLDJZ0HBIaPmKiIQAQuRUdGUs7JwAtgBGIDB8gtTjUzCiw8xSsp0K+P1eGj66qPpGpj0425Y+NnZFpeLM9k48ZDu+2vv6waYOEZLRsR+NKwE7km02S8DSKSAA)

```
// refining against null works
declare function fooA(): [string, null] | [null, string];
function A() {
    const x = fooA();

    if (x[0] === null) {
        const y = x[1]; // y = string
    }
}

// attempting to refine based on type = string, fails
declare function isString(x: any): x is string;
declare function fooB(): [string, number] | [number, string];
function B() {
    const x = fooB();

    if (isString(x[0])) {
        const y = x[1]; // y = string | number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a design limitation. You can use values (e.g. `null`) to discriminate between union members and conditionally narrow the type, but you cannot use type guards to do this. See this [TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506) (it's about objects instead of tuples, but the mechanism is the same).